# Simple DB Model

Tags: php, oop, model

I do not have much experience using frameworks or anything so that leaves me with little experience using Models (MVC). I have no interest whatsoever in using a framework at the moment. I am working on a website and I am trying to model some objects but I'm not sure exactly how I should be designing the class.

For instance, right now I have a class with a few public members which can be accessed directly. I have started prototyping some functions (select, delete, update) but I am not sure

1. If these functions should be static
2. If these functions should accept parameters or use the class members instead
3. If these functions should even exist how they do currently
4. If the entire concept I'm going for is the right thing to do

I can't seem to find any sort of hints on the interwebs as to how to create a model class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a factory class then all verbs are usually instance methods and the factory is instantiated with some sort of DB session.

If the verbs are member's of the entity's class select is usually a static method while update is usually an instance method and delete is usually defined both ways (IE: `delete(recordID)` and `entity.delete()`)

The entire concept is the right thing to do but you're going to do it wrong. Period. Making a scalable model like this takes a lot more time and effort than people have at their disposal. I know you have no interest in using a framework but you should.

Comment: Doing what you've described is actually the exact thing that I have implemented so far. This doesn't really need to be very scalable for this particular project.

Answer (score 2):

My inference from your question is that this is a low profile project, and you have enough flexibility from your boss/client/teacher that you can build it however you want. That in mind, here is what I would think about when working on this.

If MVC is a new concept to you, then Test-Driven Development is almost certainly and alien one as well. However, I first cracked into a real understanding of OOP while doing it, so I suggest you give it a try. Writing some simple unit tests first against your model classes will take you through the exercise of figuring out how those model classes are going to be used. You'll be working with the external API of each of those objects (or groups of objects if you're not a TDD purist), and that will help guide the design of the internals. Check out [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/index.html) for getting started, as the documentation has some great examples as well.

I think the TDD approach will lead you to the following conclusions:

1. Probably not. Static data/methods are usually only useful when you absolutely need one copy of something. I find in web apps that aside from maybe a resource connection like the DB this is rarely the case.
2. This depends on what the function does. Keep in mind that using local variables implies side-effects, or changes in the state of the object. If the data you need to operate on should not change the state of the entire object, use a parameter and return a value. It's also easier to test these kinds of methods.
3. Again, writing tests for these functions that illustrate how you'll use them in the application will lead you to a conclusion one way or another about whether you need them or whether they are designed correctly. Don't be afraid to change them.
4. Absolutely. How else are you going to become comfortable with MVC if you don't roll your own implementation at least once? In fact, it's probably better to grasp the concepts with real experience before you move to a more professional framework. That way, you'll understand why the concepts and conventions of the framework are the way they are.

Oh, and the lack of clarity that you're finding on what a model class is, is probably due to the fact that it's the part of your application that is most customized. This is your data model and domain logic, so a lot of it is case-specific. The best resource, though, IMHO is Martin Fowler, whose excellent book Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture goes into a lot of detail on how and why to design a particular set of "model" classes with one pattern or another. Here is the [online pattern library](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)--obviously the book is more detailed.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP, I think designing object oriented model adds extra work with little benefits - even when looking on large frameworks, it's common to just use assoc-arrays that you can get from resultsets (see f.ex. the multiparadigm approach of Zend MVC).

While Object-Relational mapping is much more established among strongly typed languages like Java, there are already tools for PHP as well (f.ex. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)). You may check it out if having OO-oriented model is what you want, but be aware that OR-mapping has severe issues of it's own and might be of little use in PHP (haven't tried it myself in a dynamic language yet).

For most newly started project, picking a good framework is usually a way to go - it can save you time and promote best practices (of course after some learning time that's different for every tool out there). When using some framework, you should always try to find out the framework's / community approach to solving specific problems (like model design & data access) before experimenting on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to abstract away data access using object-oriented concepts is a hot-button topic for a lot of people. Put another way, there are several ways to do it and there is no "one right" way.

Rolling your own works best if you are seriously upgrading an existing application. This is because you have a heap of code that is already database dependant and you have some bounds for the necessary refactoring. It also teaches you about abstracting code because a lot of refactoring involves removing (or reducing) code duplication. Once you've done this to completion, you will have a much better idea of how a data model layer should work. Or at least, should work for the way you program. And you will know what not to do next time you build one. :-)

If you're starting a new codebase and haven't worked with a framework or object layer but know you need to build one, then the best advice I can give is to be willing to build one later, and refactor the code to suit when that does happen. Yes, it will likely mean your application will get 90% rewritten a few times.

Writing an object abstraction layer is difficult and you will end up with dense code that is fairly defensive about things, and doesn't take chances. But once you've got it working, you will also know how to build robust code, because it will probably be debugged fairly thoroughly.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I have some redundant code and now I am refactoring in models to take its place.

Comment: The way I write a data object layer is to put all the core, common code into one class and derive sub-classes that know their own name and their own fields, etc, but pass the information back to the parents (I use a static function to do that when the sub-class is declared). Then you have all the heavy lifting fully paramaterised on one place.

Answer (score -1):

1. No because, static methods are hard to test
2. It depends of the parameter, life cycle, etc. Impossible to answer without seeing some code.
3. ?
4. No

OOP requires at least 10 years of experience to have a better view on what is wrong/right/better/worse.

So, if you are not a OOP expert, instead of losing too much time reinventing the wheel, I would suggest:

1. Use a well-known framework for the technical part
2. Create your classes/framework for the business/functional part.

(1) Will help you be ready in no time for the classic technical part (Session, database interaction, etc.). Will avoid you to make errors others already did.

(2) This is your core business, it should be "your DNA".

Also, using a well-known/good technical framework will make you read quality code and help you progress. (Be carefull some frameworks are really of poor quality)

When you will have enough experience, you will be able to skip the technical framework part and build/customize your own... because technical framework are usually evil (They serve too many purposes). :)